# IOS 6- value is not called in cellForRowAtIndexPath though it is defined globally

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am posting the code which I tried.I am getting string value and then I am adding it to an array and getting the array value too.But problem comes when I try to use the array value in other method ,it's value is blank.

```
//ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
      NSArray *totalData;
     NSString *stringValueVideoiD;
     NSMutableArray *TableVideoIDArray;
     NSMutableArray *TableVideoNameArray;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

//ViewController.m
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   TableVideoIDArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   TableVideoNameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self getAllRows];
   [tableView reloadData];
}

-(void) getAllRows{

 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
       NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM table"];

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,[sqlStatement UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
        {
         while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
             char *videoId = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
                stringValueVideoiD = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:videoId];
                [TableVideoIDArray addObject:stringValueVideoiD];
                NSLog(@"vids array:%@",TableVideoIDArray);
           //vids array:value is printed

             char *videoName = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
             NSString *stringValueVideoName = [[NSString alloc]     initWithUTF8String:videoName];
                [TableVideoNameArray addObject:stringValueVideoName];


 totalData=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:stringValueVideoiD,stringValueVideoName,nil];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        sqlite3_close(db);

        }
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [totalData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {

        cell=[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }

   NSLog(@"here:%@",TableVideoIDArray);
cell.channelTitle.text=[TableVideoIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//here comes the problem.My console result is
2013-09-18

11:18:24.431 AppName[468:11303] here:( ) 
2013-09-18 19:43:35.562 AppName[3991:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'//so guys I need your help why this is happenning or I am making mistakes in my code.
```

Comment: I have a couple of suggestions for you. First, don't forget to call `[super viewDidLoad]`, and in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method you are returning `totalData count` instead of `TableVideoIDArray count`.

Comment: in my actual code [super viewDidLoad] is there,my mistake for not mentioning here and in numberOfRowsInSection i removed totalData with TableVideoIDArray,but same result is happenning

Comment: If what you pasted isn't your actual code, how do you expect anyone to find the problem? :) You should post your full solution. If you have to rename variables/methods for security purposes, that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your primary problem lies in the arrays you are accessing.

In your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you use `totalData` but later in your `cellForRow...` you request your object from your array `TableVideoIDArray`.

It appears that `totalData` has elements in it while `TableVideoIDArray` does not, which is why you are getting an `indexOutOfBounds` exception. So my guessed solution is to change:

```
cell.channelTitle.text=[TableVideoIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to:

```
cell.channelTitle.text=[totalData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Again, there could be other problems but that definitely appears to be a major one.

Also, as a side note, properties and variables in objective-c should be lower case. You have two arrays that are capitalized and this is not the convention. It is also recommended now that all of your variables be accessed through property instances. So `tableData` and your other objects would then be properties themselves.

Comment: thanks Firo for your suggestion,I will surely implement your ideas.